# Will `cat ~/foo* > ~/results/output.txt` preserve the ordering of `~/foo*`?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, sort, cat

I have hundreds of files of the form `~/foo.x.y`. The files are

```
~/foo.0001.0010
~/foo.0011.0020
~/foo.0021.0030
...
~/foo.4371.4378
```

I want to combine all of these files into a big file `~/results/output.txt` where the order is preserved. I'm fairly certain that

```
$ cat ~/foo* > ~/results/output.txt
```

accomplishes this but I'm not sure if this command will respect the ordering of my `foo` files. Does this command work? If not, how can I accomplish my task?

Comment: The examples you have given will be matched in order by `foo.*`, you should try to add as many examples as possible to have a greater matching surface, and better precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat` will follow the order of the arguments, if you expand `~/foo*` (in some shells double tab, or `echo ~/foo*`) you will see the order.

The order of the `*` wildcard is alphabetic.

SO globbing question:
https://superuser.com/questions/192280/does-bashs-match-files-in-alphanumeric-order

Comment: right, but I'm curious if `~/foo*` is *guarenteed* to respect the ordering.

Comment: Good question: http://superuser.com/questions/192280/does-bashs-match-files-in-alphanumeric-order

Comment: `ls` by default will likely sort based on something, `echo *` or `printf "%s\n" *` might be better

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

```
After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans
each word for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of these characters
appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an
*alphabetically* sorted list of filenames matching the pattern
```

Note `alphabetically`. In your case it will be:

```
$ cat foo.0001.0010 foo.0011.0020 foo.0021.0030
```

You can expand `*` with <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> after typing `*` and before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.